# Solving fractional differential equations in Matlab using fde12 function

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

```
function dfdt=myfun(t,x)

    dfdt = [...
        x(2);
        (1.5*((x(2))^2)*(cos(3*(x(1)))))-(((pi/2)^2) * ...
            (sin((pi*t)/2)))-(20*((x(1))-(sin((pi*t)/2)))) - ...
            ((0.5*((x(2))^2)*abs(cos(3*(x(1)))))+0.1) * ...
            sat(((x(2)-((pi/2)*cos((pi*t)/2))) + ...
            (20*(x(1)-(sin((pi*t)/2)))))/0.1)-(((abs(sin(t)))+1) * ...
            (cos(3*x(1)))*((x(2))^2))
];
```

`sat` in this equation is defined as follows:

```
 function f = sat(y)
     if abs(y) <= 1
         f = y;
     else
         f = sign(y);
     end
```

I am solving it first as an ODE using ODE45 where I define the  differential equations as a vector:

```
   [t, x] = ode45(@myfun, [0 4], [0 pi/2])
```

This works fine. But when I try to solve the same set of equations using [`fde12`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32918-predictor-corrector-pece-method-for-fractional-differential-equations):

```
[T,Y] = FDE12(ALPHA,FDEFUN,T0,TFINAL,Y0,h)
```

Now I call it:

```
t0 = 0;
tfinal= 4 ;
h = 0.01;
x0 = [0 pi/2];
[t, x] = fde12(0.95, @myfun, t0,tfinal, x0,h);
```

(`alpha` is the order of fractional differentiation, e.g., `0.95`)

it gives the following error:

```
Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x) = 1.
```

Comment: One word of advice: those looooooong lines of code are very, *very* hard to read, let alone debug. Use a few substitutions to make it more clear, if only to do yourself a favor for when you come back to this code half a year from now...

Comment: But have you tried to do something with `fde12`? Are there specific points in its documentation you don't understand? Also, is there any particular reason you prefer `fde12` over `ode113 `(Adams-Bashforth-Moulton PECE solver)?

Comment: Thank you. I've solved this equation with ode45. I want to solve this equation with fractional derivative.

Comment: IF you go to your `myfun(t,x)` and place a `disp(x), disp(t)` at the top, what does that show you?

Comment: The function `sat` can be written as `sat = @(x) min(+1,max(-1,x));`

Comment: disp(x) have Matrix (n,2) and for disp(t) have Matrix  (n,1)

Comment: nothing . process of fde12 is  different.

Comment: i think fde12 defined defferently and equation of fde12 must write Other state

Comment: You can ask new questions but this one was part of a question/answer pair. Just let this go and focus on the new question.

Comment: **AGAIN**: Please STOP editing this question to ask something else. [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: If you can do it or write a simple example!??? You think you've solved the problem, but you're wrong! It is incomplete! Form of a differential equation is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM - or in this case: [the description](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32918-predictor-corrector-pece-method-for-fractional-differential-equations):

> The set of initial conditions Y0 is a matrix with a number of rows equal to the size of the problem

Yet, you specify

```
x0 = [0 pi/2];
```

This has two columns. If you change it to two rows:

```
x0 = [0; pi/2];
```

It will work. (I just tried with your example).

Comment: @MiladGreeneyes: Why the "unaccept" of the answer?

Comment: @MiladGreeneyes: Instead of changing this question, and then unaccepting an answer that made sense before - why don't you ask a **NEW** question?

Comment: Write the equation in the form fde12 is different with ode45 I'm looking at the issue of how to modify the equation in this form.